# Generate a matrix for a given recurrence relation

Tags: matrices, recurrence-relations

For recurrence relation

$f(n) = af(n-1) + bf(n-2) $

the corresponding generated matrix is

$ $$\begin{bmatrix} f(n) \\ f(n-1) \end{bmatrix}$$ = $$\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$ $$\begin{bmatrix} f(n-1) \\ f(n-2) \end{bmatrix}$$ $

So how should I go about generating the same for the recurrence relation

$f(n) = f(n-1) + 2^{n/2}$

Thanks.

Comment: There'e no such matrix. It's not a homogeneous linear recursion.

Comment: It makes no math sense to put this in matrix form, since it doesn't help in any way. But if you really have to, then you've got it right there $\;[\,f(n)\,] = [\,1\,] \cdot [\,f(n-1)\,] + [\,2^{n/2}\,]\;$ where each term is a $1\text{x}1$ matrix.

Comment: I want to solve this relation through matrix exponentiation. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: `solve this relation through matrix exponentiation` That only works for homogeneous linear recursions, and yours is not (as quasi noted already). The associated homogeneous recursion would be $f(n)=f(n-1)$ but you don't need matrices or exponentiation to solve that. What's left to do here is find a particular solution for the given non-homogeneous recursion.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help  :)

Answer (score 1):

The main idea of finding the matrix is to achieve a more explicit expression of $f$. But if you have $f(n)=f(n-1)+2^{n/2}$. Then notice that

$f(n)=2^{n/2}+f(n-1)=2^{n/2}+2^{(n-1)/2}+f(n-2)=\cdots=2^{n/2}+2^{(n-1)/2}+\cdots +2^{1/2}+f(0)=\frac{2^{1/2}-2^{(n+1)/2}}{1-2^{1/2}}+f(0)$

Answer (score 0):

To solve the recursion, you can use the "telescoping" trick . . .

Thus:

\begin{align*}
f(1) - f(0) &= 2^{\frac{1}{2}}\\[4pt]
f(2) - f(1) &= 2^{\frac{2}{2}}\\[4pt]
&\;\;\vdots\\[4pt]
f(n) - f(n-1) &= 2^{\frac{n}{2}}\\[12pt]
\implies\; f(n) - f(0) &= 2^{\frac{1}{2}}+2^{\frac{2}{2}} + \cdots + 2^{\frac{n}{2}}\\[4pt]
&= r + r^2 + \cdots + r^n&&\text{[where $r=\sqrt{2}\,$]}\\[4pt]
&= \frac{r^{n+1}-r}{r-1}\\[4pt]
&=
\frac{\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^{n+1}-\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}-1}\\[4pt]
&= \frac
{2^{\frac{n+1}{2}}-\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}-1}\\[12pt]
\implies\;f(n) &= f(0)+
\frac
{2^{\frac{n+1}{2}}-\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}-1}\\[12pt]
\end{align*}